# I want to merge 2 tabs into 1 page with using Selenium Python.Concretely,each page has just 1 tab and the result page has 2 tabs

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wrote below code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome() 
driver1.get('https://www.google.com/')
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome()
driver2.get('https://www.yahoo.com/')
```

Of course this code finally create 2 pages but I want to merge it into 1 page.

How do I implement it?.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want multiple tabs in one window?

I believe there's no such function in Selenium. However, you can run JavaScript to open a URL in a new tab using the `execute_script()` function.

```py
driver.get("https://google.com")

script = "window.open('https://www.yahoo.com/','_blank');"
driver.execute_script(script)
```

Hope this helps.